# 24h time after midnight order

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, time

I'm facing this problem.  When I wrap times from websites I'm always getting a 0:00h or 0:30h for example.  This is technically at the beginning of the current date.  But for humans is at the end of current date.

I need 0:00 to 6:00 get sorted at the end of the day instead of beginning, directly from data-base.

I'm using java, hibernate criteria, mysql datetime.
Thanks all!

Comment: Where is the cutoff from one "day" to the next? Is it at "24:59"? "25:00"?

Comment: You really haven't provided enough context to get a real answer.  Where do you want to get these times sorted differently?  On a web page? In a query result-set? Are the times stored as `Date` objects in the database? As strings? We need a better description of the requirements.

Comment: I agree with the on-hold decision. My answer was based partly on guesswork, always a risky thing. Please consider editing your question to explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've updated my question. Is it clear enought?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your dates and times ordered correctly by using MySql `DATETIME` data types throughout your application.  The Java equivalent class is `util.Date`.

According to computer and telecommunications industry standards, the first millisecond of each calendar day has the time 00:00.000.  So, if you add ten seconds to 23:59:51.000 you get 00:00:01.000 on the next day.

It sounds like your business has a different, non-standard, rule for describing the beginning and ending of each day, to use for this particular display. That's fine. But you need to enumerate this rule very precisely indeed. Midnight matters in many fields of human endeavor!

Let's say your rule is that a day's information runs from [01:00:00 to 01:00:00) the next day.

Then you can select yesterday's records in a MySQL query like this.

```
WHERE `timestamp` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
  AND `timestamp` < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
  ...
ORDER BY `timestamp`
```

This will display your stuff in the right order.  It won't display the time 24:01, but it will place 00:01 after 23:59.

Comment: This seems to be a simple & good answer I'll try it tomorrow & I will feed back. Thanks Ollie!

Comment: I don't see the way I can integrate it with hibernate and my complicated Criteria list. I didn't find a way to integrate sql in hibernate Order clause.  Finally I've created a varchar date column in database with this value YYYYMMDDHHMM where I save hours as 24 instead of 00, and then I get the list ordered by this column